# Java int scanner with blank input

Tags: int, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get an int scanner that will accept a blank entry instead of ignoring every \n until there is an input.

Suggestions?

Comment: Posting your code showing what you've tried so far would always be a good start. In this case, I'd recommend searching a bit since there are lots of threads about how to use scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
stringIN = userIN.nextLine();
```

will accept a blank entry. userIN is my scanner name and stringIN is the variable I'm setting that input to.

Comment: but I need my scanner to scan int not Strings so nextLine() is no good.

Comment: wrap it in a try catch block:




    try {
    stringIN = userIN.nextLine();
    TEST1 = Integer.parseInt(stringIN);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.print("input a number dummy!");
   }

Comment: Will give it a go!